# How to work with mat-paginator to work with several request instead of request all the data first?

Tags: angular, rest, angular-material, material-ui, mat

I have a view in the project that retrieves all the information (json) we want to show in the mat-paginator, but the problem is that it is getting very slow because every day we have thousands of new rows in the list. The solution is to request each new range of data for every page to make it more quick. The question is if Mat-paginator has a configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can be fixed the records for the page and then load on scrolling the list or table

For example. in **component.ts**  file

```
// List/table scroll some variables
  pageStart: number = 0;
  pageEnd: number = 100;
  pageHeight: number = 30;
  pageBuffer: number = 100;

// on list/table  scroll 
  onScroll(event) {
    const scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = event.target.scrollHeight;
    const offsetHeight = event.target.offsetHeight;
    const scrollPosition = scrollTop + offsetHeight;
    const scrollTreshold = scrollHeight - this.pageHeight;
    if (scrollPosition > scrollTreshold) {
      this.pageEnd += this.pageBuffer;
    }
  }
```

And in **component.html** file

```
<div class="example-table-container"  (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
// and  here you can use datatable or list anything
</div>
```